# How to populate account fields on component after selecting account from dropdownlist?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to display account fields in the component after selecting any of the account from dropdown list. How can I achieve this anyone help me on this please.

Component :

```
            <aura:component controller = "AccountDetailsComponent" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
                <!-- handler -->
                <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />    
                <!-- attributes -->
                <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List"/>
                <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="List"/>
                <!-- Account Dropdown section1 -->
                <div class="slds-size_4-of-12">
                 <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
                      <thead>
                          <tr class="slds-text-heading_label">
                               <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Accounts">Accounts</div></th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>        
                      <tbody>
                        <lightning:select label="Accounts" aura:id="accountName">
                              <option value="" text="- None -" />
                              <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
                                  <option value="{!acc.Name}" text="{!acc.Name}"  />               
                              </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:select>                                   
                     </tbody>            
                    </table> <br/>
                     <lightning:button label="Submit" class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.contactsList }" /><br/><br/>
                </div> <br/><br/>

                <!-- Details section2 -->
                <div class="slds-page-header">
                    Account Details
                    <div> 
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact1">
                             <lightning:outputField  fieldName="{!contact1.Account.Name}" /> 
                             <lightning:outputField  fieldName="{!contact1.Account.Industry}" />
                             <lightning:outputField  fieldName="{!contact1.Account.Phone}" /> 
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Related list section3 -->
                <div class="slds-page-header">
                    Related Contacts
                <div>
                  <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-heading_label">
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="ID">ID</div></th>
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div></th>
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Email">Email</div></th>
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Phone</div></th>        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Id}">{!contact.Id}</div></th>
                                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Name}">{!contact.Name}</div></td>
                                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Email}">{!contact.Email}</div></td>
                                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Phone}">{!contact.Phone}</div></td>                   
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
                </div>
              </div>   
            </aura:component>
```

.JS

```
            ({
                doInit : function(component, event, helper){

                    var action = component.get('c.getAccountsList');
                    action.setParams({
                        //no parameters required

                    });

                     action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                         component.set('v.accounts', response.getReturnValue());
                    });

                    $A.enqueueAction(action);       
                },
                contactsList : function(component, event, helper){

                    var action = component.get('c.getContactDetail');
                    var selectedAccountName= component.find("accountName").get("v.value");
                    console.log(selectedAccountName);
                    action.setParams({

                        "accountName" : selectedAccountName

                    });
               action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                         component.set('v.contacts', response.getReturnValue());
                    });
                    $A.enqueueAction(action);       
                }
            })
```

Apex Class

```
 public class AccountDetailsComponent {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccountsList(){
    List<Account> accts = [SELECT id,Name,Industry,Phone FROM Account limit 10];
                     return accts;        
                }

    @AuraEnabled  
    public static List<Contact> getContactDetail(String accountName){
    List<Contact> cons;
    if(accountName != ''){
            cons = [SELECT id,Name,email,Phone,Account.Industry,Account.Phone,Account.Name From Contact WHERE Account.Name = : accountName];  

        }return cons;
    }
  }
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In apex class, create a wrapper class which contains both account fields and list of contact and return this wrapper to component. Below is the code,

```
public class AccountDetailsComponent {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccountsList(){
    List<Account> accts = [SELECT id,Name,Industry,Phone FROM Account limit 10];
                     return accts;        
                }

    @AuraEnabled  
    public static List<Contact> getContactDetail(String accountName){
    List<Contact> cons;
    Account accObj;


    if(accountName != ''){
            accObj = [Select Id,Industry,Phone,Name FROM Account where Name=:accountName];
            cons = [SELECT id,Name,email,Phone From Contact WHERE AccountId = : accObj.Id];  

        }
        AccountWithContactWrapper wrapperObj = new AccountWithContactWrapper();
        wrapperObj.accountObj = accObj;
        wrapperObj.listContactObj = cons;
        return wrapperObj;
    }
    public class AccountWithContactWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Account accountObj;
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Contact> listContactObj;
    }
  }
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountDetailsComponent" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <!-- handler -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <!-- attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="contactWrraperObj" type="Object" />
    <!-- Account Dropdown section1 -->
    <div class="slds-size_4-of-12">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-heading_label">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Accounts">Accounts</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <lightning:select label="Accounts" aura:id="accountName">
                    <option value="" text="- None -" />
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
                        <option value="{!acc.Name}" text="{!acc.Name}" />
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <lightning:button label="Submit" class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.contactsList }" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <!-- Details section2 -->
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        Account Details
        <div>
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.contactWrraperObj.accountObj.Name}" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.contactWrraperObj.accountObj.Industry}" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.contactWrraperObj.accountObj.Phone}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Related list section3 -->
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        Related Contacts
        <div>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading_label">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="ID">ID</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Email">Email</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Phone</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactWrraperObj.listContactObj}" var="contact">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Id}">{!contact.Id}</div>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Name}">{!contact.Name}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Email}">{!contact.Email}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Phone}">{!contact.Phone}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller JS:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get('c.getAccountsList');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            component.set('v.accounts', response.getReturnValue());
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    contactsList: function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get('c.getContactDetail');
        var selectedAccountName = component.find("accountName").get("v.value");
        console.log(selectedAccountName);
        action.setParams({
            "accountName": selectedAccountName
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            component.set('v.contactWrraperObj', response.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```